# Suggested Edit - Community Reject

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I was just editing a question apparently at the same time as the OP, which in turn caused my edit to be *rejected* with a message of *This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit*. I am totally cool with this as the OP was adding more information which my edit would have wiped out..

My question is this, do Community Rejects like this count against me in my Editor Stats?

Comment: Probably?  I see it just as rejected suggestion on [your activity page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454538/enki-dev?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).  I have to look at the review itself to get the rejection reason.  Luckily this doesn't happen very often.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conflicting edits are included in the stats on the review page

> [image]

though don't count towards the too-many-rejections-ban.

(if you also ask why in [your suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1454538/enki-dev?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) you see one rejection and two approvals lacking - that's because of the posts you've edited having been removed afterwards)