# Edit rejections conflicting with previous edits should not be reflected in a user's "rejected edits" statistics

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

This is a request to change how we handle rejected edits that are solely rejected because they conflict with a previous edit.

I went looking to find out if these rejections are reflected in a user's 'rejected edit' statistics, and was pointed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309912/suggested-edit-community-reject).

Some of the time, these edits are not 'bad' edits. I can not speak to the percentage of these that may be considered 'bad' but the ones that have been reflected on me have been almost exact to the final submissions.

I find that it is a bit unfair to have these statistics changed simply based on the fact that a higher rep. user was able to edit the question before your edit could be reviewed. If one would argue that there needs to be a chance to reject it as a bad edit, then it would need to continue on to be approved/denied based on a human review.

I do concern myself, even if it is trivially, with the prospect of future reviewer bias against my potential edit because of an amount of 'rejected edit's that are potentially not my fault. *Disclaimer I know that most users with rep. high enough are stand-up members of the community.

'Fairness' when it comes to the lost opportunity at gaining a good edit on your stats I will accept as necessity because, after all, it is important to review lower rep. user's edits.

All of this considered, is there a possibility of not having an edit rejected based on confliction with a previous edit *not* be reflected in the rejected edit statistics for a user?

Is it possible when a higher rep user edits a question for the system to automatically kick all pending edit suggestions out of the review queue to neither be approved or denied, but possibly just deleted?

To reiterate an issue brought up in the 'dupe question' post- My level of editing ability should not be based on superfluous 'rejected' edits that I have no control over.

*Based on my specific suggestions to handle the issue -that are not reflected elsewhere, I have decided not to delete this question.

Comment: For what it's worth: users don't actually see your suggested edit stats when they are reviewing your suggested edit. That's only shown after the fact.

Comment: @CodyGray good to know! a tidbit i really did not know. I suppose that makes that section a moot point, but the request remains the same.

Comment: Sure, it's a fair request. The issue is almost certainly going to be the complexity of implementing it. The way it's handled now, the Community user (who has mod privileges) just rejects the edit. A new special case would need to be added to the code for "conflicting" edits, and all for not a whole lot of benefit. Also, I just found a dupe. :-)

Comment: nice find! you're much better at finding them than me. I really do look for them, I swear.

Comment: @CodyGray so what happens to that feature request, since the question is neither approved or denied as has long since gone stagnant?

Comment: Not at all unusual. Nothing special happens. Related discussion: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354713/what-percent-of-meta-feature-requests-are-read-or-seriously-considered Also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266782/on-meta-how-do-you-get-attention-for-questions-without-an-answer and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317708/bringing-attention-to-old-meta-questions-when-you-cant-edit